# Spring JPA projection - selecting specific columns in nested object list

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Why I get the following error:

> query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched
> association was not present in the select list

when I try to get List of ids?

```
@Query("SELECT at.id FROM Template at " +
            "WHERE at.shipper.id = :companyId " +
            "AND at.isActive = true")
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"shipper"})
    List<Long> findTemplateIdsByCompanyId2(Long companyId, Pageable pageable);
```

but when I want to get list of objects - everything is OK?

```
@Query("SELECT at FROM Template at " +
            "WHERE at.shipper.id = :companyId " +
            "AND at.isActive = true")
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"shipper"})
    List<Template > findTemplateIdsByCompanyId2(Long companyId, Pageable pageable);
```

`Template` entity has `OneToOne`  relationship with `shipper` field and `OneToMany` relationship with `warehouse` field

Answer (score 0):

You need to join in the query if you are not fetching the entity, something like this should do it:

```
SELECT at.id FROM Template at JOIN at.Shipper s WHERE s.id = :companyId and at.isActive = true
```